# Differential equation : $y' = (x+1)/(xy+x)$

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

So, I have the following differential equation to solve : $$y' = \frac{x+1}{xy+x}$$
After several steps, I get here :

$t^2 + 2t = 2x + 2ln(x) + c$

How do I isolate $t ?$

thank you!

By the way, $ t=f(x)=y$

Comment: Completing the square is fine; $t^2+2t$ is already pretty close to being a perfect square as-is.

Comment: I can factorize, but how do I only get one letter "t" ?

Comment: Add 1 to both sides...

Comment: ah ok, yeah thank you I see now

Comment: what is the need for a new variable $t?$

Comment: I just wanted to make it more easier to read, that's all.  (I replaced f(x) with t)

Answer (score 1):

Start by dividing through by $x$:
$$
y'=\frac{1+\frac{1}{x}}{y+1} \\
y'(y+1)=1+\frac{1}{x} \\
\int y'(y+1)dx=\int 1+\frac{1}{x}dx \\
\frac{y^2}{2}+2y=2x+2\ln(x)+c~\text{for constant $c$} \\
y^2+2y+1=2x+2\ln(x)+2c+1 \\
(y+1)^2=2x+2\ln(x)+2c+1 \\
y+1=\pm \sqrt{2x+2\ln(x)+2c+1} \\
y=\pm \sqrt{2x+2\ln(x)+2c+1}-1.~_{\square}
$$

Answer (score -1):

let $W$ denote [Lambert's W-function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). after taking exponentials of both sides:
$$
Ae^{\frac12(t+1)^2} = xe^x =W^{-1}(x)
$$
so we have
$$
x = W(Ae^{\frac12(t+1)^2})
$$
if this is correct, then we have:
$$
t = \sqrt(2\log( A^{-1}W^{-1}(x)))-1
$$

Comment: OP is not solving for $t$ in terms of $x$.

Comment: can be turned round simply enough. however the legendary demon downvoter now seems to be doing his rounds, so i shall wash my hands of this sordid affair!

Comment: Sure. If you're hiking towards a destination and you mistakenly go the complete opposite direction for an hour, after you realize your mistake you can turn around and go back to where you started, and then from there go the correct direction toward the destination. But telling others to go the wrong way does not constitute good directions to a fellow hiker. I figured once you realized your post needed to be withdrawn you would delete it - this sort of thing is routine - but when you didn't I was confused, and in any case downvoted. It's doubtful I'm "legendary"; I haven't downvoted you before.

Comment: no probs. i'm still unfamiliar with some of the details of etiquette at MSE, so didn't realize a deletion was expected. this is one of the problems with anonymous downvoting - no explanation is given, so a person may not be aware of the nature of the offence committed. otherwise i am very happy to have my errors pointed out - it's one of the ways we learn, after all.

Comment: Why is your formula for $t$ so convoluted? There is no reason to write $W^{-1}(x)$ instead of $xe^x$, for example. Just solve the quadratic already given in the OP instead of circumnavigating the globe to travel a few miles!

Comment: thx for that. +1 for the good advice